# Why Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty is Not equal to the instance.__proto__.hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, class, google-chrome, prototype, proto

This is my code, my class, my instance

language: javascript

```js
class People {
    constructor (name) {
        this.name = name
    }
    eat () {
        console.log(`${this.name} eat something`)
    }
}

class Student extends People {
    constructor (name, number) {            
        super(name)
        this.number = number
    }
    learn () {
        console.log(`student ${this.name} is learning`)
    }
}

class Teacher extends People {
    constructor (name, major) {
        super(name)
        this.major = major
    }
    teach () {
        console.log(`${this.name} teacher ${this.major}`)
    }
}

// instance
const xialuo = new Student('xialuo-name', 100)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xeQxS.jpg)

**Why does this happen when I execute my code in Chrome.**

```js
xialuo.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty === Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty // true
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty === xialuo.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnPerperty // false
```

What is happen ???

Why the previous line code is return true.

The next line of code return false ???

I am so confusing

Answer (score 0):

There is typo issue **hasOwnPerperty**

Change

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty === xialuo.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnPerperty
```

to

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty === xialuo.__proto__.__proto__.__proto__.hasOwnProperty
```